# LeetCode: Rotting Oranges in C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, interview-questions, breadth-first-search

https://leetcode.com/problems/rotting-oranges/
Please review for coding style in 40 minutes job interview.

> In a given grid, each cell can have one of three values:
>
> the value 0 representing an empty cell; the value 1 representing a
>   fresh orange; the value 2 representing a rotten orange. Every minute,
>   any fresh orange that is adjacent (4-directionally) to a rotten orange
>   becomes rotten.
>
> Return the minimum number of minutes that must elapse until no cell
>   has a fresh orange.  If this is impossible, return -1 instead.
>
> ```
> Example 1:
>
> Input: [[2,1,1],[1,1,0],[0,1,1]]
> Output: 4
> Example 2:
>
> Input: [[2,1,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1]]
> Output: -1
> Explanation:  The orange in the bottom left corner (row 2, column 0) is never rotten, because rotting only happens 4-directionally.
>
> Example 3:
>
> Input: [[0,2]]
> Output: 0
> Explanation:  Since there are already no fresh oranges at minute 0, the answer is just 0.
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> 1. 1 <= grid.length <= 10
> 2. 1 <= grid[0].length <= 10
> 3. grid[i][j] is only 0, 1, or 2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace GraphsQuestions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/problems/rotting-oranges/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class RottingOrangesTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ExampleTest()
        {
            int[][] grid =
            {
                new []{2, 1, 1 },
                new []{1, 1, 0},
                new []{0, 1, 1}
            };
            Assert.AreEqual(4, RottingOrangesClass.OrangesRotting(grid));
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void BadExampleTest()
        {
            int[][] grid =
            {
                new []{2, 1, 1 },
                new []{0, 1, 1},
                new []{1, 0, 1}
            };
            Assert.AreEqual(-1, RottingOrangesClass.OrangesRotting(grid));
        }


    }

    public class RottingOrangesClass
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// we will use BFS and not DFS because we can move in one step to all of the directions.
        /// not one by one and in this way we will get the best result
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="grid"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static int OrangesRotting(int[][] grid)
        {
            if (grid == null || grid.Length == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int countFreshOranges = 0;
            Queue<int[]> Q = new Queue<int[]>();
            for (int row = 0; row < grid.Length; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < grid[0].Length; col++)
                {
                    if (grid[row][col] == 2)
                    {
                        Q.Enqueue(new int[] { row, col }); // we save the rotten oranges
                    }
                    else if (grid[row][col] == 1)
                    {
                        countFreshOranges++; // we count the fresh oranges
                    }
                }
            }

            if (countFreshOranges == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int count = 0;
            while (Q.Count > 0)
            {
                count++;
                int size = Q.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    int[] point = Q.Dequeue();

                    //try all directions
                    int x = point[0];
                    int y = point[1];
                    countFreshOranges = TryDirection(grid, x + 1, y, Q, countFreshOranges);
                    countFreshOranges = TryDirection(grid, x - 1, y, Q, countFreshOranges);
                    countFreshOranges = TryDirection(grid, x, y + 1, Q, countFreshOranges);
                    countFreshOranges = TryDirection(grid, x, y - 1, Q, countFreshOranges);

                }
            }

            if (countFreshOranges == 0)
            {
                return count - 1;
            }

            return -1;
        }

        private static int TryDirection(int[][] grid, int x, int y, Queue<int[]> Q, int countFreshOranges)
        {
            //check out of bounds
            //also check for no orange or already rotten
            if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= grid.Length || y >= grid[0].Length || grid[x][y] == 2 || grid[x][y] == 0)
            {
                return countFreshOranges;
            }

            grid[x][y] = 2;
            Q.Enqueue(new int[] { x, y });
            countFreshOranges--;
            return countFreshOranges;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your

```
private static int TryDirection(int[][] grid, int x, int y, Queue<int[]> Q, int countFreshOranges)
```

method I would invert the logic: If the given coordinate is valid and the field contains a fresh orange, then do something:

```
private static int TryDirection(int[][] grid, int x, int y, Queue<int[]> Q, int countFreshOranges)
{
    if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < grid.Length && y < grid[0].Length && grid[x][y] == 1)
    {
        grid[x][y] = 2;
        Q.Enqueue(new int[] { x, y });
        countFreshOranges--;
    }
    return countFreshOranges;
}
```

That is shorter and easier to understand.

The while loop in

```
public static int OrangesRotting(int[][] grid)
```

does one iteration more than is necessary: When all fresh oranges have rotten, another loop iteration is needed to empty the queue. That is also the reason why `count - 1` is returned in the success case. It becomes clearer if both `countFreshOranges` and the queue are checked in the while condition:

```
int count = 0;
while (countFreshOranges > 0 && Q.Count > 0)
{
    count++;
    // ...
}
return countFreshOranges == 0 ? count : -1;
```

That makes also the preceding check

```
if (countFreshOranges == 0)
{
    return 0;
}
```

obsolete.

Some more thoughts:

- Use an `enum` type (with values `Free`, `Fresh` and `Rotten`) instead of the integer constants `0`, `1`, `2`, so that the code becomes more self-explaining.
- Instead of pushing `int[]` onto the queue, a tuple with two elements, or a `struct` with two members `x` and `y` would be sufficient.
- `Q` is too short as a variable name, it does not tell what the variable is used for.